# Netty SSL exceptions handling with endpoint context

Tags: ssl, error-handling, netty, spring-webflux

We're using `netty 4.1.31` (via `spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.0.7`)

Our server is being called using two-way SSL and it works. The SSL is configured using Spring Boot's [`server.ssl` properties section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-ssl).

Since we require the SSL authentication (`server.ssl.client-auth=NEED`), there is a general exception every time a client tries to access an endpoint using unsecured HTTP. Such as:

```
ERROR --- [ctor-http-nio-3] r.i.netty.channel.CloseableContextHandler  : Handler failure while no child channelOperation was present 
io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: ...
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1178) [netty-handler-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1243) [netty-handler-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:502) [netty-codec-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:441) [netty-codec-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:278) [netty-codec-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434) [netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965) [netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) [netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:648) [netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:583) [netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:500) [netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:462) [netty-transport-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897) [netty-common-4.1.31.Final.jar:4.1.31.Final]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

How do I customize the error handling to **log the REST endpoint path related to the SSL exception**?

I tried to handle it naively at the `@RestController` level, but it won't catch it.

```
@ExceptionHandler(NotSslRecordException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Void> exceptionHandler(NotSslRecordException ex) {
    ...
}
```

I probably need to customize some parts of [Netty](https://netty.io/) around the [SslHandler](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/handler/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/ssl/SslHandler.java), but not sure how. Any ideas how to approach this?